# URL with special characters are not rendered correctly in chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When posting links that contain special characters like e.g.:

http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/backen_(Konjugation)

the closing ')' is not included in the URL displayed.

Comment: See also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66472/url-detecting-error-with-address-like-http-en-wikipedia-org-wiki-octet-comput).

Comment: Not just in chat - here too.

Comment: ty @Tim N this how to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design; some URL formats, including plain, can't deal with ending parens.

See:
[Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses/13509#13509)

For other linking formats that will work properly with ending parens.

In particular, using the editor URL toolbar button (or pressing CTRL+L) will work fine.

Comment: Wow. Jeff honours our humble little site. ("D'uh. Of course I know him. We're practically pals. He left a comment on *our* meta site!")